# Upgrading application in android market

Tags: android, upgrade

I am trying to upgrade my android application in android market. I had updated version code and version name in manifest file.

```
android:versionCode="3" android:versionName="2.0"
```

I had used the same key for sign the application. I am getting error as 'The APK must be signed with the same certificates as the previous version'. How can i upgrade my app.

Comment: i feel you sign with wrong certificate. please find correct and update.

Comment: For first time i had created a private keystore for sign my application. After that i am using the same keystore to export new apk, after updating version code and version name.

Comment: but there are some certificate was generate so please find fist because its most important to upgrade app

Comment: If you are absolutely sure about the signing key, check path of apk, whether you are uploading the exported apk or the debug apk from bin directory

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to have the same **keystore** file which you have used to upload the 1st version of application on android market. If you have lost this keystore file then you can't provide update to this application.

So in your case, you have to have that keystore file, sign the version 3 apk with this keystore file and upload on the market.

From Android doc: [Publishing Updates on Android Market](http://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/publishing.html)

> **Publishing Updates on Android Market**
>
> At any time after publishing an application on Android Market, you can
>   upload and publish an update to the same application package. When you
>   publish an update to an application, users who have already installed
>   the application may receive a notification that an update is available
>   for the application. They can then choose to update the application to
>   the latest version.
>
> Before uploading the updated application, be sure that you have
>   incremented the android:versionCode and android:versionName attributes
>   in the  element of the manifest file. Also, the package name
>   must be the same as the existing version and the .apk file must be
>   signed with the same private key. If the package name and signing
>   certificate do not match those of the existing version, Market will
>   consider it a new application, publish it as such, and will not offer
>   it to existing users as an update.

Answer (score 0):

You must use the same key and the same key alias.